# Need to align 'Modify' button in all browsers correctly with date and time field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 'Modify' button correctly in all browsers but in FF and IE it is displaying little bit below from date and time field
'Modify' button should be aligned with Date and time piker horizontally.

i'am using this style:

```
style="position:absolute; right:35px; top:145px;" 
value="Modify" 
dates="" 
id="btndate" 
onclick="ModifyDates();"
```

Comment: Can you show a demo?

Comment: It would be great if you can show the URL where you are trying this code, that way we can check on different browsers. Thanks